# Wie wird eine Halskette genannt, die nicht aus Kettengliedern besteht?

Tags: single-word-request

Halsbänder und Halsketten sind Schmuckstücke, die um den Hals getragen wird.
Der Duden spezifiziert nichts Genaueres. Aus Wikipedia lässt sich folgender Unterschied herauslesen:

- [Halsbänder](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halsband) liegen nahe am Hals bzw. eng am Hals an und sind deshalb inetwa kreisrund.
- [Halsketten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halskette) sind länger als Halsbänder und hängen in den Brustbereich herunter.

Das Wort "Hals**kette**" impliziert, dass es sich um eine [technische Kette](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kette_(Technik)) handelt und deshalb aus Kettengliedern besteht. Es gibt aber auch Halsketten aus z.B. Lederschnüren, welche keine Kettenglieder haben und deshalb keine technischen Ketten sind.

Gibt es ein Wort, das solche Halsketten, die keine technischen Ketten sind, bezeichnet? Wie lautet es?

**Edit:**
Wie in den Kommentaren erklärt geht es mir weniger um eine exakte Definition, sondern darum, in der Lage zu sein, so ein Schmuckstück effizient zu benennen.
"Halskette aus Leder" bzw. "Lederhalskette" sind die mir am sinnvollsten erscheinenden Möglichkeiten, das "**kette**" suggeriert aber trotzdem eine typische Halskette mit Kettengliedern aus Metall.

Comment: Riemen oder Lederriemen.

Comment: Warum müssen Halsbänder eng anliegen? Ich würde eine Schnur oder einen Lederriemen auch als Halsband bezeichnen. Wikipedia zu Halsketten: "Es gibt [...] auch Schnüre, auf die Perlen, Muscheln oder Edelsteine aufgereiht sind." Sieht aus, als würde der Begriff "Kette" in Bezug auf Schmuck keine technische Kette voraussetzen. Ein Teekesselchen, wenn Du willst.

Comment: Ich verstehe das Abgrenzungsbedürfnis nicht. *Kette* ist ein sehr generischer Begriff, DWDS definiert ihn als *viele beweglich miteinander verbundene Glieder, die ein fest zusammenhängendes Ganzes, oft in Form eines Bandes bilden*. Die *technische Kette* ist der Spezialfall, und ich sehe nicht , dass man beim allgemeinen Begriff unterstreichen müsste, dass es sich nicht um den speziellen handelt.

Comment: @Janka Aber das hat dann nichts mit **Hals**ketten zu tun. Also ein Lederriemen kann auch ein Antriebsriemen für eine Maschine sein.

Comment: @Robert "eng anliegen" oder "nahe am Hals liegen". Also nicht wie eine Halskette herunterhängend. Siehe auch nächsten Kommentar.

Comment: @guidot Mir geht es hier weniger um die exakte Definition, sondern um den praktischen Nutzen. Ich möchte möglichst effizient kommunizieren, dass es keine Kettenglieder hat und in den Brustbereich herunterhängt. "Halskette aus Leder" ginge zwar, aber es klingt ungewöhnlich, da "Hals**kette**" eine typische Halskette mit Kettengliedern aus Metall suggeriert.

Answer (score 7):

> Halskette

Selbst die klassische *Perlenkette*  hat keine technische Eigenschaften einer Kette. Sprache ist nicht immer ganz perfekt, und auch nicht immer pingelig.

Ich denke, deine Annahme, dass eine Halskette aus Kettengliedern bestehen müsse, die ineinander greifen, ist falsch. Ich nenne als zusätzliche Beispiele mal "Bergkette", "Inselkette", "Telefonkette", denen alle die *technische Eigenschaft* einer Kette fehlt.

Comment: +1. Siehe auch den Wikipediaeintrag zu Ketteln.

Comment: Das stimmt, ich möchte aber anmerken, dass alle aufgeführten Beispiele aus diskreten Objekten bestehen, die in einer Reihe angeordnet sind. Charakteristisch für eine Kette. Diese Eigenschaft fehlt z.B. einer Schnur.
(Eine Perlenkette verwendet innen zwar eine Schnur, aber diese sieht man üblicherweise nicht.)

Answer (score 4):

Wenn man den Unterschied zu einer "technischen Kette" besonders betonen möchte, kann man den Begriff

> Collier

verwenden. Ein Collier ist ein Halsschmuck, dessen Elemente aus Materialien wie Perlen, Korallen oder Edelsteinen bestehen.

Allerdings besagt auch der genannte Wikipedia-Artikel nicht, dass eine Halskette eine "technische Kette" aus metallenen Kettengliedern sein muss. Im Abschnitt "Ausführung" ist beschrieben, dass eine Halskette "neben den rein metallenen Ketten auch Schnüre, auf die Perlen, Muscheln oder Edelsteine aufgereiht sind" sein kann.

Alternativ dazu könnte man auch den Oberbegriff

> Halsschmuck

verwenden. Da dieser aber naturgemäß auch die "technischen" Halsketten umfasst, stellt das den Unterschied nicht gut dar, so dass das für mich nur die zweite Wahl wäre.

Comment: was den beschriebenen schnüren und auch perlenketten gemeinsam ist, sind allerdings die aufgereihten elemente. die machen erst den kettencharakter aus. ein einfaches lederband wäre demnach keine kette.